# PHP adjacent list (parent child) loop

Tags: php

So i am working on referall system,

Let's say there is one parent named User A. User A Invites 2 users, User B and C.

- User B bought 2 Items
- User C bought 4 items
- Level 1 total = 6 Items.

And then User B invites user B1 and B2, then User C invites C1 and C2.

- User B1 bought 1 item
- User B2 bought 1 item
- User C1 bought 2 item
- User C2 bought 1 item
- Level 2 total = 4 items

And so on.

The level defines the "batch" of invited user.

I am just able to find the first level total items. here is my code (I am using CI)

```
$user_children = $this->_model->all(' AND referral_id = '.$id);
    if(count($user_children) > 0){
        foreach($user_children as $child){
            array_push($users,$child); 
        }
    }
```

I couldn't iterate through the grandchildren..

How to write a function that will return total items bought per level? have been dealing with it quite a while. Can somebody help me? thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could build a recursive function to calculate your values:

```
function calc_level($id,$level_array){
   $user_children = $this->_model->all(' AND referral_id = '.$id);
    if(count($user_children) > 0){
        foreach($user_children as $child){
            $level_array[$child->id] = $level_array[$child->id] + $child->items_bought; 
            $level_array = calc_level($child->id,$level_array);
        }
    } 
    return $level_array;    
}
```

Assuming '*id*' and '*items_bought*' are the names of your database columns.

And call like this:

```
$level_array = array();
$level_array = calc_level('id_of_first_level',$level_array);
```

It will return an array with your level ids as index and total bought as values.

I am not sure if this is the correct way to implement in CI.